# Are equilateral polyhedra with triangular faces rigid?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

*For the purposes of this question, a polyhedron has triangular facets.*

Convex polyhedra are rigid by Cauchy’s theorem. [Steffen’s polyhedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffen%27s_polyhedron) is an example of a non-convex polyhedron that is flexible (i.e., non-rigid). However, it appears to have edges of different lengths. My question: **are there equilateral flexible polyhedra or are all equilateral polyhedra rigid?**

*Motivation: I have a bars-and-balls magnetic construction set and I would like to build a flexible polyhedron. But all the bars I have are equal in length.*

Comment: FYI: A polyhedron with equilateral-triangle faces is a [Deltahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron).

Comment: Take two regular tetrahedra with only an edge in common: there's your flexible deltahedron.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca this wouldn’t meet the common definition of a polyhedron.

Comment: If your edges are not perfectly rigid, you can consider a equilateral pentagonal Siamese dipyramid. It is not mathematically flexible but you can continuous deform it with relative variation of edge lengths within $0.5\%$. (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.09233.pdf)).

Comment: @achillehui The reference you mention uses isosceles non-equilateral triangles. Also, like you mention, the polyhedron is not flexible (perhaps not even infinitesimally flexible).

Comment: My understanding of that paper is there are 3 configuration where equilateral triangular faces are possible.

Comment: @achillehui Perhaps you are referring to Fig. 4. My understanding is that these are different isometric embeddings. But that's beside the point since, like you mentioned, none are flexible. Configuration (b) of Fig. 3 looks more promising as there is a hint of infinitesimal flexibility.

Comment: Do you allow self-intersection? or $180^\circ$ dihedral angles?

Comment: A "Bricard decahedron", two pentagonal pyramids attached at their bases, might be flexible. The problem with the Bricard octahedron is that the two square pyramids coincide when it's equilateral. Pentagonal pyramids should have an extra degree of freedom, so they wouldn't necessarily coincide.

Comment: [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlexiblePolyhedron.html) refers to a flexible polyhedron found by Paul Mason, but it's not clear what it is. The way I interpret the description would give it 32 equilateral triangle faces, not 34.

Comment: @mr_e_man Any reason to believe that Mason's polyhedron is equilateral?

Comment: I see no reason it couldn't be equilateral. Attach a regular-faced square antiprism to a cube; the result has 8 triangle faces and 6 square faces. Then attach a regular-faced pyramid to each square face; the result has 8+6*4=32 triangle faces and no remaining square faces. However, I don't know if this is Mason's polyhedron, or if this is flexible.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427453/are-polyhedra-with-equilateral-triangular-faces-rigid

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment, a polyhedron with congruent equilateral triangles for faces is called a "deltahedron".  [This reference](https://grusfield.com/tsuruta/deltahedron/) lists "Bellows deltahedra" as flexible deltahedra that seem to meet OP's criteria.  It shows two distinct examples, and also links to another (possibly semi-defunct) website with additional images and descriptions of these objects.  If I'm understanding the images correctly, the simplest example has $48$ faces and a $6$-fold rotational symmetry.

Comment: The semi-defunct website says that these tetrahedra are rigid since the equatorial angle determines the mouth opening.